# Upload fails with Status Code: 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch when multiPartUpload is true

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

I created a simple camel route to poll for files in a local directory and upload them to a Ceph (S3) server at my University. I am using apache camel 2.20.0 with the camel-aws S3 component, when I set multiPartUpload=false (the default) in the uri, everything works fine, but if I change to multiPartUpload=true, it fails.

I know there is nothing wrong with my s3 secret or s3 access key because when I set multiPartUpload=false, everything works (there are no crazy plus (+) characters that need to be escaped in the keys).

Here is the stack trace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: tx000000000000002e9edee-005a4ed3d2-2213a2-uky-campus-1; S3 Extended Request ID: 2213a2-uky-campus-1-uky)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1592) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.abortMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:2928) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.186.jar:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.processMultiPart(S3Producer.java:181) ~[camel-aws-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.process(S3Producer.java:84) ~[camel-aws-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at ...
```

My camel-context.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="properties"
        class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
        <property name="location" value="config.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder"
        class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="location" value="config.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="amazonClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
                <constructor-arg name="accessKey" value="${s3AccessKey}" />
                <constructor-arg name="secretKey" value="${s3SecretKey}" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="s3ClientOptions">
            <bean class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3ClientOptions">
                <property name="pathStyleAccess" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="endpoint" value="${s3Endpoint}" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="file:target/sendToS3/?antInclude=*.*" />

            <log message="Found file: ${in.header.CamelFileName}" />

            <setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3Key">
                <simple>testMultiPart/${in.header.CamelFileName}
                </simple>
            </setHeader>

            <setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3ContentLength">
                <simple>${in.header.CamelFileLength}
                </simple>
            </setHeader>

            <log message="Send file to S3: ${properties:s3Endpoint}" />

            <to uri="aws-s3://{{s3Bucket}}?amazonS3Client=#amazonClient&amp;multiPartUpload=true" />

            <log message="Done sending file." />

        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I have tried a lot of things like:

- setting the CamelAwsS3ContentMD5 header to the MD5 hash of the file (which doesn't make sense for multi-part files)
- various settings for the partSize parameter
- different sized files from very large to very small
- setting the system parameter: System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.disablePutObjectMD5Validation", "true");

If I turn on trace debugging for camel, it doesnt help much:

```
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] S3Producer                     TRACE Initiating multipart upload [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest@3731147a] from exchange [Exchange[ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1]]...
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] S3Producer                     TRACE Uploading part [1] for testMultiPart/testfile.zip
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            TRACE Is exchangeId: ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1 interrupted? false
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            TRACE Is exchangeId: ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1 done? false
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            TRACE isRunAllowed() -> true (Run allowed if we are not stopped/stopping)
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultExceptionPolicyStrategy TRACE Finding best suited exception policy for thrown exception com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultExceptionPolicyStrategy TRACE Finding best suited exception policy for thrown exception com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultExceptionPolicyStrategy TRACE Found 0 candidates
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            DEBUG Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: tx000000000000002e9edee-005a4ed3d2-2213a2-uky-campus-1; S3 Extended Request ID: 2213a2-uky-campus-1-uky), S3 Extended Request ID: 2213a2-uky-campus-1-uky
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            TRACE isRedeliveryAllowed() -> true (we are not stopping/stopped)
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            TRACE This exchange is not handled or continued so its marked as failed: Exchange[ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1]
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] InstrumentationProcessor       TRACE to: Recording duration: 356930 millis for exchange: Exchange[ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1]
[d #2 - file://target/sendToS3/] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-Toucan-local-1515115111374-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: tx000000000000002e9edee-005a4ed3d2-2213a2-uky-campus-1; S3 Extended Request ID: 2213a2-uky-campus-1-uky), S3 Extended Request ID: 2213a2-uky-campus-1-uky
```

The reason I need multi-part uploads to work is for very large files, but I can't get it to work on any file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out...

Since the endpoint is a Ceph server, multipart uploads won't work unless you set signerOverride to 'S3SignerType' in the S3 ClientConfiguration like this:

```
<bean id="amazonClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
            <constructor-arg name="accessKey" value="${s3AccessKey}" />
            <constructor-arg name="secretKey" value="${s3SecretKey}" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

 <!-- *** The following option must be set in order for multipart uploads to work on a Ceph server *** -->
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
            <property name="signerOverride" value="S3SignerType" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>


    <property name="s3ClientOptions">
        <bean class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3ClientOptions">
            <property name="pathStyleAccess" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="endpoint" value="${s3Endpoint}" />
</bean>
```

Maybe this requirement will go away in later versions of Ceph, the one I am connecting to is older than v12 (Luminous), but I am not sure of the exact version. Or, maybe this is a limitation of the HTTPS front-end serving the Ceph cluster - I am not sure.